# Install Windows XP to an USB

Tags: windows-xp, liveusb, sp2

Not like "Windows Setup" in that USB, I meant the live OS as I need a live recovery environment to fix my PC when it leads to trouble
https://archive.org/details/super-nano-xp
Here's the link I've used to download Windows XP image

Comment: What’s your question?

Answer (score 0):

I see the link you shared is for an ISO.

Once you have downloaded it , If you want to create a bootable USB you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/). Once the drive is created you can just boot to it from your PC's BIOS. It will be treated just like a Windows recovery disk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).